# writing draft blog posts without the new_post() function

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I'm trying to write a blog using *blogdown*. However, I may be drafting three or four posts at any given time without a firm date to release any of them. I certainly don't want any of them showing on my public site. How can I start these posts within the content/post directory, without

- without assigning them dates,
- and while hiding them from view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked [on Github](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/97#issuecomment-307660501) and answered there. Basically you can use the filename extension `.Rmarkdown` instead of `.Rmd`, and also add `draft: true` to the YAML metadata of the post.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at Github but must not have seen that answer to my question.